# Using aggregate functions with CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a query on Postgres, that uses data of a CTE, that at the sample below I called subq.

But at the moment that PSQL reads this line of code

```
WHEN MAX(date_) > subq.max_date_table_1 THEN 0
```

It returns the following message to me:

```
ERROR:  column "subq_history.max_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

---

My entire query:

```
WITH
subq AS (
    SELECT id_table_1, COUNT(*) AS count_table_1, DATE(MAX(date_)) AS max_date_table_1
    FROM table_1
    WHERE DATE(max_date_table_1) > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL '30 DAYS'
    GROUP BY id_table_1
)

SELECT table_2.id_table_2,
CASE
    WHEN MAX(date_) > subq.max_date_table_1 THEN 0
ELSE 
    subq.count_table_1
END AS
    RESULT
FROM table_2, subq
AND table_2.id_table_2=subq.id_table_1
GROUP BY table_2.id_table_2;
```

I really believe that I'm facing this error because I'm not calling the subquery at the right way.

Comment: Can you articulate what the logic of your `CASE` expression is intended to be?

Comment: It must be 0 when the MAX(date) of table "table_2" is bigger than MAX(date) of subq (subquery). Else, it has to be the count of subq (subquery).

Comment: Where is the JOIN or WHERE clause for your main query?

Comment: does [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bdae8901fd3ae6489991fcd647af747c) solve your problem?